# Pandas, get pct change period mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame which contains a column like this:

```py
      pct_change
0           NaN
1     -0.029767
2      0.039884 # period of one
3     -0.026398
4      0.044498 # period of two
5      0.061383 # period of two
6     -0.006618 
7      0.028240 # period of one
8     -0.009859
9     -0.012233
10     0.035714 # period of three
11     0.042547 # period of three
12     0.027874 # period of three
13    -0.008823
14    -0.000131
15     0.044907 # period of one
```

I want to get all the periods where the pct change was positive into a list, so with the example column it will be:

```
raise_periods = [1,2,1,3,1]
```

Comment: what is the criteria for a period of one, two, or three?

Comment: @JoeFerndz it's every time that there is one or more positive values in the column, I want to count those until the next drop and then start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the column of your dataframe is a series called `y` which contains the `pct_changes`, the following code provides a vectorized solution without loops.

```
y = df['pct_change']
raise_periods = (y < 0).cumsum()[y > 0]
raise_periods.groupby(raise_periods).count()
```

Comment: Caveat: Use `(~(y > 0)).cumsum()` if an `nan` between positive numbers is considered as termination of a consecutive positive number stream. Otherwise `(y<0).cumsum()` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

eventually, the answer provided by @gioxc88 didn't get me where I wanted, but it did put me in the right direction.

what I ended up doing is this:

```py
    def get_rise_avg_period(cls, df):
        df[COMPOUND_DIFF] = df[NEWS_COMPOUND].diff()
        df[CONSECUTIVE_COMPOUND] = df[COMPOUND_DIFF].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0)
        # group together the periods of rise and down changes
        unfiltered_periods = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(df.consecutive_high.values.tolist())]

        # filter out only the rise periods
        positive_periods = [li for li in unfiltered_periods if 0 not in li]
```

I wanted to get the average length of this positive periods, so I added this at the end:

```py
period = round(np.mean(positive_periods_lens))
```